# Remote debugging with cobalt

Tags: debugging, chromium, cobalt

I'm trying to remote debugging with cobalt.
I launch cobalt like this:

`cobalt --remote-debugging-port=9222`

after that I launch chrome with this url http://ip_adress_device_cobalt>:9222

when I try to navigate in  developer tools tabs , the console works fine but other tabs (like network, source) are always empty.
so I'am unable to use breakpoints for example or monitiring the network.

is there any other configure to do?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: According to Stack Overflow policy, questions must contain code. For product questions, please refer to cobalt-dev@googlegroups.com.